# using regex for searching strings in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, search

Hi I have been trying to search a string pattern in Visual Studio 2010 using regex. The string pattern is something like "abc[somevar].ppfunc"

Now "abc" and "ppfunc" are fixed terms but "somevar" could be any string of any length. For example: it could be abc[xyz].ppfunc or abc[ghid].ppfunc or abc[blah].ppfunc

What wild card should I use in place of "somevar" so that search results should contain all possible words present in the code.

I tried abc[*].ppfunc  and abc[.*].ppfunc (in Find and replace box of VS) but it didn't work.

any quick suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the regex based find and replace feature of VS2010, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28VS.100%29.aspx). 
To do so, ensure that regex expressions are enabled:

> To enable regular expressions, expand Find options in the Find and Replace window, select Use, and then select Regular expressions. The triangular Expression Builder buttons next to the Find what and Replace with fields become available.

And then construct a regex that matches what you want to replace.